# Bootstrap Footer Gaps left and right when resized to mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added a new footer to my twitter boostrap website but when I resize the window gaps appear on the left and right.

I know that this is related to this css code...

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 body {
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
```

}

If I change the padding to 0px then footer gaps go away but the whole page looses a margin.

I have tried this but it didn't work.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 footer {
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
```

}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using negative margins, the same approach the nav uses. I didn't try this, but something like this should work:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    footer {
        padding-left: -20px;
        padding-right: -20px;
    }
}
```